# show validation error message from rails model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to show validation error messages from controller by making our method ? please check the code below

```
validate :validation
  def validation
    if self.RJan.nil? && self.RFeb.nil? && self.RMar.nil? && self.R1.nil?
      #How do write my error message here ?
    end
  end
```

and my form

```
<% if @record.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@record.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this record from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @record.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add errors to your instance using

```
self.errors.add(:base, "your message here")
```

You could put attributes name as symbol instead of `:base` or whatever you like.

In your case

```
if self.RJan.nil? && self.RFeb.nil? && self.RMar.nil? && self.R1.nil?
  self.errors.add(:base, "your message here")
end
```

Comment: so in the model in the if block i should write self.errors.full_messages ?

Comment: apparently something is wrong and it is not showing error message for any validation!

Comment: I answered your other thread. The code above is just to add new errors to your instance. Nothing to do with views or display mechanisms