# How to validate attr_accessor ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my model i have :code attr_accessor

```
<%= text_field_tag :code, "", class: 'form-control text optional', placeholder: 'Code' %>
```

When the form is submitted, i get from params the :code, and i want so validate some errors

controller

```
@tourney_subscribe = TourneySubscribe.new(params.tourney_subscribe)

validate_code(params[:code]) if params[:code].present?
#now it adds the error

# when .valid? it clean the error
if @tourney_subscribe.valid?
...
else
   render :next
end
```

but in my controller i'm using .valid? and it clean the errors and then don't show the :code error

In this case how to treat errors with an attr_accessor?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56237998/how-to-get-validations-error-messages-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305192/show-validation-error-message-from-rails-model

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show validation error message from rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305192/show-validation-error-message-from-rails-model)

Comment: What is `validate_code(params[:code])` and `params.tourney_subscribe`?

Comment: method that checks the code and add the error if it should be

Answer (score 0):

You can validate virtual attribute as usual model attribute, for example

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :code

  validates :code, presence: true
end
```

And other validations too

Comment: i need to pass a param from view to controller and then validate on controller adding  an error to model, but using validate or valid? it cleans the error

Comment: that is checked before the model errors

Comment: If you add error to some record, it will not be cleaned. How your code looks? Add to the question text. Probably you initialized new model instance and that's the problem

Comment: i've added some controller code